# PHP Delete rows from database if they no longer exist in the API

Tags: php, mysql, api

I'm trying to create something like:

- When you make a POST request to the API, insert those values into the MYSQL database
- Delete them if they longer exist in the API (since the API only returns active values)

Inserting works, but deleting doesn't work quite as good.

Right now I think it's looping through the request and deleting every ID that isn't a match EACH time. So it ends up deleting everything by the end of the loop.

How do I fix this?

```
<?php
include 'import.php'; // Import from API
include 'connect.php'; // Connect to DB


// Add and Update on duplicate
foreach ($query as $val) {
    $fruitId = $val['fruitId'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO basket (fruitId) 
        VALUES ('$fruitId') 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        fruitId = '$fruitId'";


    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "ID has been added";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating ID";
    }   
}

// Delete
foreach ($query as $val) {

    $fruitId = $val['fruitId'];

    $sql = "DELETE FROM basket 
            WHERE fruitId NOT IN ('$fruitId')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "ID has been deleted";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating ID";
    }   
}
?>
```

Not sure if there's a better/more concise way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a fake database

```
fruitId fruitName
1       apple
2       orange
3       banana
4       kiwi
5       tomato
```

Look this code

```php
$sql = "DELETE FROM basket 
            WHERE fruitId NOT IN (4,5)";
```

What happen here... Delete everything exept id 4 and 5... So 1 to 3 is deleted

Next is id 3

```php
$sql = "DELETE FROM basket 
            WHERE fruitId NOT IN (3)";
```

Delete the last id 4 and 5... Other query will just be ignore and not return any error

You will need to think another way, but you need to know exactly what **should** be deleted